# Mount a directory to look like a drive

Tags: mount

Is it possible to mount a directory, either an ext# local one, or one in a /media mounted windows drive, so it is seen as a mounted drive itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only want quick access to a certain directory in Nautilus and the file dialogs, you can also use a bookmark of course...

Anyway, there is a FUSE filesystem named `bindfs` (`sudo apt-get install bindfs) that probably does exactly what you want.  For example the following:

```
bindfs -n /media/USB-HDD-01/ISO/ /home/johnc/ISO-images
```

would result in `ISO-images` to show up as a mounted filesystem in the *Places* sidepanel in Nautilus.  The `-n` is required because otherwise `bindfs` tries to use the `allow_other` FUSE option, which by default is not allowed for regular users (if you use `bindfs` in `/etc/fstab` this is not a problem).

The first directory you give is the existing one, the second directory you give is an empty directory under which the contents of the existing one will appear.

To unmount, use:

```
fusermount -u /home/johnc/ISO-images
```

---

PS: Nautilus (the file manager) will show mountable/mounted *filesystems*, not *drives*, but I assume that's what you were looking for.

Comment: A smidge of extra info:  You may create a "bind" mount without using FUSE.  sudo mount -o bind from_dir to_dir.  I believe the result is the same though and using the FUSE filesystem does not require sudo access.

Comment: @KFro: with "mount --bind" it will not show up in the Nautilus "Places sidebar" though (I tested that before answering).

Answer (score 2):

If you mount a folder using a transparent fusefs system, gnome will pick it up and show it as a drive. You'll loose some overhead in the calls, but not much for a fast machine.

You could also make a gvfs system that mounts a folder, or a localhost ftp, ssh or other type of mount. That will show as a drive too.